# Counting a walk $i \rightarrow j \rightarrow k \rightarrow j \rightarrow l \rightarrow j$ in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

[This paper](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/45690/11336_2005_Article_BF02288782.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) gives a procedure for counting redundant paths (which I will refer to as *walks*) in a graph using its adjacency matrix. As an exercise, I want to count only the walks of the form $i \rightarrow \color{blue}j \rightarrow k \rightarrow \color{blue}j \rightarrow l \rightarrow \color{blue}j$ from node $i$ to node $j$, with $ i \neq j \neq k \neq l$. Also see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676178/matrix-of-paths-from-graph-g-1-to-graph-g-2-to-graph-g-3).

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix. The notation I use below is: "$\cdot$" for usual matrix multiplication, "$\odot$" for element-wise matrix product, "d$(A)$" for the matrix with the same principal diagonal as $A$ and zeros elsewhere, and $S = A \odot A^T$.

The matrix for $i \rightarrow \color{blue}j \rightarrow k \rightarrow \color{blue}j \rightarrow l \rightarrow \color{blue}j$ will have its $i$, $j$ entry: $a_{ij}\cdot a_{jk}\cdot a_{kj}\cdot a_{jl}\cdot a_{lj}$. I have found this to be:
$$
A \cdot (d(A^2))^2
$$

However, $i \rightarrow \color{blue}j \rightarrow k \rightarrow \color{blue}j \rightarrow l \rightarrow \color{blue}j$ also includes the following walks which repeat undesired nodes and should be subtracted:
$$
\color{red}i \rightarrow j \rightarrow \color{red}i \rightarrow j \rightarrow l \rightarrow j \tag{1} $$
$$ \color{red}i \rightarrow j \rightarrow k \rightarrow j \rightarrow \color{red}i \rightarrow j \tag{2} $$
$$ i \rightarrow j \rightarrow \color{red}k \rightarrow j \rightarrow \color{red}k \rightarrow j \tag{3} $$
$$\color{red}i \rightarrow j \rightarrow \color{red}i \rightarrow j \rightarrow \color{red}i \rightarrow j \tag{4} $$

My calculations for $(1) - (4)$ are:
$$ S \cdot \text{d}(A^2) \tag{1} $$
$$ \text{d}(A^2) \cdot S \tag{2} $$
$$ A \cdot \text{d}(A^2) \tag{3} $$
$$ S \tag{4} $$

Every time one of $(1) - (3)$ is subtracted, $(4)$ is subtracted as well, since it is included in all three. Since it is not desired in the end, it is added back 2 times. Overall:
$$ A \cdot (d(A^2))^2 - S \cdot \text{d}(A^2) - \text{d}(A^2) \cdot S - A \cdot \text{d}(A^2) + 2S$$

However, this is wrong and gives incorrect counts, even negatives. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the problem. The approach and formulas seem to be correct. What I did not consider is that they work for directed graphs, so $(i, j) \neq (j, i)$. This means that the matrix for each term has to be added to its transpose. Each terms also counts pattern $(4)$ twice, so it needs to be added $4$ times, not $2$. At the end, the matrix is divided by two.

If we have
$$
\text{sym}(M) = M + M^T
$$

Then the formula I ended up with is:
$$
[\text{sym}(A \cdot d(A^2)^2) - \text{sym}(S \cdot \text{d}(A^2)) - \text{sym}(\text{d}(A^2) \cdot S) - \text{sym}(A \cdot \text{d}(A^2)) + 4S] \div 2
$$
(sym can be moved to the outside)